# IIS 10.0 error 2280 while executing 32 bit

Tags: iis, windows-10, visual-studio, 32-bit, dll

While trying to make a local deploy of a rest-api that requires to be executed on 32bit, the server stops the application pool under witch it runs.

The events viewer:

> error while loading "C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\aspnetcore.dll."
>   code 2280.

Any solution?

Visual Studio does debug perfectly but local IIS does not...

Answer (score 1):

If any application requires to be run under 32 bit in IIS, you need to go to the advanced settings under the application pool and changed `Enable 32-Bit Applications` from **False** to **True**

Comment: Sorry for not including that info on the question but that´s somethign I've already done. It does not Works even with the 32 bit application enabled...

Comment: Have you tried using Failed Request Tracing in IIS? To see if that can pinpoint the issue?

Comment: Yes I did it does not log anything... The FiledReqLogFiles folder remains empty.

Comment: Did you enabled Failed request tracing at the website level and expand the server code it captures? and did you test it by hitting a page that doesn't exist to generate a 404 error? So you know you it's logging.

Comment: Actually trying to hit a non existent resource in the server also responses the 503 and stops the corresponding application pool:

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Service Unavailable</TITLE>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <h2>Service Unavailable</h2>
        <hr>
        <p>HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.</p>
    </BODY>
</HTML>`

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved reinstalling:
Microsoft .Net Core 1.0.1 - VS2015 Tooling Preview 2

and rebooting the system.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has an issue after adding "Configure Native Modules" and 2280 Module DLL failed to load.  Try this:

Open and edit "applicationHost.config" file located

Under   "C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config"  good to make backup copy before changes.  Find your DLL and remove the line.